# Python ATM, issues with simple subtraction?

Tags: python

This was my first experiment using Python classes and not sure why it doesn't withdrawal (subtract) from the balance. Any idea what I did wrong?

```
# ATM class with all functions
class ATM:
    def __init__(self, balance, interest=0.1):
        self.balance = balance
        self.interest = interest
        self.transactions = []

    def check_balance(self):  # checks balance
        return f"Your balance is: ${self.balance}"

    def deposit(self, amount):  # deposits to balance
        self.balance += amount
        print(f"Deposit amount: {amount}")
        return self.balance

    def check_withdrawal(self, amount):  # checks balance to see if we can withdraw
        if self.balance - amount > 0:
            return True
        else:
            print('Not enough funds to withdraw.')

    def withdraw(self, amount):  # *withdraws $$$$$$$$*
        if self.balance - amount:
            return f"You have withdrawn ${amount}"


# testing
checking_account = ATM(50000)
print(checking_account.check_balance())
print(checking_account.check_withdrawal(900))
print(checking_account.withdraw(900))
print(checking_account.check_balance())
```

Comment: you don't seem to be updating `self.balance` in `withdrawal` function

Answer (score 1):

```
def withdraw(self, amount):  # *withdraws $$$$$$$$*
        if self.balance - amount:
            self.balance = self.balance - amount
            return f"You have withdrawn ${amount}"
```

change your withdraw function, as you are not saving the deducted amount to your balance